# Is there an alternative to np.reshape for gridded data with gaps?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dataset which is gridded data which has been flattened into single columns of  x, y and z data, but I would like to get it back into a grid to run a 2D fourier transform on it. Unfortunately there are some gaps in the data around the ages of the grid.

For regular grids, using `np.reshape` would work to put this data back into a grid, but since there are gaps this will not work. Is there a similar function which will allow me to reshape and add in nans?

An example dataset (although my data has over 80,000 entries).

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2 , 3, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, -3, -2,-1,0])
y = np.array([0,1,2, 3, 1, 2,3,4, 3,4, 5, 3, 4,5,6])
```

which I would like to get into the form:

```
x = array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
   [-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
   [nan, -1.,  0.,  1.],
   [-3., -2., -1.,  0.]])

y = array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [nan,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

[This data set plotted as a scatter graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmuH.jpg)

Comment: From your original 1D vectors x and y, how are you supposed to know where the gaps are?

Comment: Also, why are the integers in your original 1D x vector different to the vectors in your reshapes x matrix (the vector has multiple 0s and negative numbers, whereas the matrix has one zero, and all other integers are strictly positive)?

Comment: Also, do you know the height and width of the final matrices in advance?

Comment: Apologies, I'd copied the final y matrix accidentally in place of the final x matrix

Comment: The gaps are all around the edges, but I don't know where they are exactly (at least not without plotting the data).

Comment: I can work out where the data changes rows with np.where(x[:-1] >  x[1:])[0], so I could work out the shape that the data should be in the end by calculating the sum of the rows and columns I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial solution. Currently it assumes that data is missing from the left or right hand side of the grid (IE it doesn't yet handle top and bottom). It also assumes that the data increases across columns (if otherwise, you just need to swap a `>` for a `<` and the bodies of the `if`/`else` statements), and that the change across rows is less than the change from the first column to the last column (if this is not true then you have a harder problem on your hands). Depending on how you data is generated, you may also want to replace the `==` with a condition to test whether or not the two values being compared are relatively close/less than the differences between values at the end of the rows.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2 , 3, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, -3, -2,-1,0])

def vector_to_array(x, verbose=False):
    # Reformat into list of lists
    x_grid_list = [[x[0]]]
    for i in x[1:]:
        if i > x_grid_list[-1][-1]:
            x_grid_list[-1].append(i)
        else:
            x_grid_list.append([i])
    
    # Calculate width and height
    height = len(x_grid_list)
    width = max(len(i) for i in x_grid_list)

    # Fill in missing data
    for row_ind in range(1, len(x_grid_list[1:])):
        row = x_grid_list[row_ind]
        if len(row) < width:
            if row[0] == x_grid_list[row_ind - 1][0]:
                # Missing data is on the left hand side
                x_grid_list[row_ind] = [np.nan] + row
            else:
                # Missing data is on the right hand side
                x_grid_list[row_ind] = row + [np.nan]

    # Convert to np array, print if verbose, and return
    x_array = np.array(x_grid_list)
    if verbose:
        print(x)
        print(x_grid_list)
        print(x_array)
    return x_array

x = np.array([0, 1, 2 , 3, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, -3, -2,-1,0])
vector_to_array(x, True)
print("*" * 50)
x = np.array([0, 1, 2 , 3, -1, 0, 1, 2, -2, -1, 0, -3, -2,-1,0])
vector_to_array(x, True)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  2  3 -1  0  1  2 -1  0  1 -3 -2 -1  0]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [-1, 0, 1, 2], [nan, -1, 0, 1], [-3, -2, -1, 0]]
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [-1.  0.  1.  2.]
 [nan -1.  0.  1.]
 [-3. -2. -1.  0.]]
**************************************************
[ 0  1  2  3 -1  0  1  2 -2 -1  0 -3 -2 -1  0]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [-1, 0, 1, 2], [-2, -1, 0, nan], [-3, -2, -1, 0]]
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [-1.  0.  1.  2.]
 [-2. -1.  0. nan]
 [-3. -2. -1.  0.]]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you - but this function does not seem to work on the y array I gave in my initial example? The x and y arrays have the gap at the same place, so having caluculated where the gaps are can those be applied straight to the y array (and a z array)?

Comment: Good point. It works for the x array and not for the y array because the x array decreases down the rows whereas the y array increases down the rows. So you'd need to find some way of deciding whether the data is increasing or decreasing down the rows (bearing in mind if you only decide this based on a single comparison, then the result could be thrown off by missing data, so you might want to make multiple comparisons), and make changes to the function to handle either case

Comment: If you want to find all the locations where an array is equal to`np.nan`, you can use the `numpy` function `np.isnan`, EG `np.isnan(vector_to_array(x))`. You could then take the answer from this and use it to insert `nan`s in the correct place in `y` and `z`